# Como recuperase de un Flux.error()

Tags: spring-boot, programación-reactiva, junit-4

soy nuevo en reactor. Quisiera saber cómo recuperar un flujo de un Flux.error()
Tengo el siguiente metodo

```
 public Flux<String> messageNode() {
        return Flux.just("0x1", "0x2")
                   .concatWith(Flux.error(new RuntimeException("Service shutdown unexpectedly!")))
                   .concatWith(Mono.just("0x3"));
    }
```

y quisiera pasar la siguiente prueba:

```
/**
     * Consume all the messages `messageNode()`.
     * Ignore any failures, and if error happens finish consuming silently without propagating any error.
     */
    @Test
    public void under_the_rug() {
        Flux<String> messages = messageNode()
                             //todo: change this line.                             

        ;
                                

        //todo: change this line only
        ;

        StepVerifier.create(messages)
                    .expectNext("0x1", "0x2", "0x3")
                    .verifyComplete();
    }
```

Sin embargo esto no parece funcionar. El metodo onErrorContinue se recupera de errores en un mismo flujo, pero no cuando se concatena con un Flux.error().